# Keras LSTM Shape for Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I'm playing around with machine learning and trying to follow along with some examples but am stuck trying to get my data into a Keras LSTM layer.

I have some stock ticker data in a Pandas DataFrame which is resampled at 15 minute intervals with ohlc and a load of other metrics for each row.

My code is below. df is my DataFrame:

```
x = df.iloc[:, :-1].values
y = df.iloc[:, -1:].values

dimof_input = x.shape[1]
dimof_output = len(set(y.flat))

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(4, input_dim=dimof_input, return_sequences=True))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='rmsprop')

model.fit(x, y, nb_epoch=1, batch_size=1, verbose=2)
```

When I try and fit I get:

```
Error when checking input: expected lstm_16_input to have 3 dimensions, 
but got array with shape (33, 100)
```

I've copied this from examples elsewhere. I can't quite see how to get the correct shape of data into this model. Can anyone help?

Thanks loads.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve with LSTM?

Comment: I'm following some tutorials for stock price forecasting. Mainly it's just as a problem to muck about with though rather than anything serious.

Comment: Ok... maybe it has to do with your `dimof_input` which you get by doing `x.shape[1]` ... What is the shape of `x`? Usually I just do `x.shape` without the index...

Comment: @Ludo Did you manage to figure this out? Would like to see how to get from a df to 3D tensor...

Answer (score 4):

**Input shapes**

3D tensor with shape `(batch_size, timesteps, input_dim)`, (Optional) 2D tensors with shape `(batch_size, output_dim)`. (from [there](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent)).
And you specified `input_dim=dimof_input`. Model expects 3D tensor as input, but got 2D. If you give a reference to the tutorial that is being implemented I probably will be able to say more about causes of the problem.
You could try reshape your input data as following:

```
x = x.reshape(x.shape[0], 1, x.shape[1])
```

Also, some information about input data of Keras LSTM layer input data could be found [here](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/2045).

Comment: Thanks! Trying your suggested reshaping now changes the error to:

    ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_17_input to have shape (None, None, 1) but got array with shape (33, 1, 100)

I think I must be fundamentally misunderstanding how these input shapes work.

I've now managed to lose the tutorial I was following along with. Let me try and find it. Thanks for your help.